# understanding references usage

Tags: php, reference

i thought, that i understand what references do.
but now i meet an example, which can't understand anyway.

i saw an interesting script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116330/recursive-categories-with-a-single-query/3116426#3116426), but why he use `&` in this script i can't understand.
here is the part of script

```
foreach ($nodeList as $nodeId => &$node) 
{
    if (!$node['id_parrent'] || !array_key_exists($node['id_parrent'], $nodeList)) 
    {
        $tree[] = &$node;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $nodeList[$node['id_parrent']]['children'][] =&$node;
    }
}
```

if he doesn't make any **changes** on $node, why it is needed to use references here?
there is nothing like `$node = any changes`, so why use =& $node, instead $node?

maybe you will help me to understand?

Thanks

Comment: understanded. thanks much (p.s it is very useful thing, references:)

Comment: This is something they teach you in `C` language courses. You're asked to create a link-list using C arrays; this is the same except instead of storing references to prev/next you store references of children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tree[] = &$node;`

When you do it like this, the tree array will store references to the same nodes as in the node list. If you change a node from the node list, it will be changed in the tree too and vice-versa of course. The same applies to the children array.

Without using references, the tree and children array would simply contain a copy of the node.

Answer (score 1):

> if he doesn't make any changes on $node, why it is needed to use references here? there is nothing like $node = any changes, so why use =& $node, instead $node?

Because using a reference also saves you from copying the variable, thus saving memory and (in a usually negligeable dimension) performance.

Comment: Actually that is not the case anymore with objects, as of PHP 5.
In fact the entire call-time pass-by-reference construct is deprecated in PHP 5.3 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look at:

[PHP: Pass by reference vs. Pass by value](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/php/pass_by_reference.html)

This easily demonstrates why you need to pass variables by reference (`&`).

Example code taken:

```
function pass_by_value($param) {
  push_array($param, 4, 5);
}

$ar = array(1,2,3);

pass_by_value($ar);

foreach ($ar as $elem) {
  print "<br>$elem";
}
```

The code above prints 1, 2, 3. This is because the array is passed as value.

```
function pass_by_reference(&$param) {
  push_array($param, 4, 5);
}

$ar = array(1,2,3);

pass_by_reference($ar);

foreach ($ar as $elem) {
  print "<br>$elem";
}
```

The code above prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. This is because the array is passed as reference, meaning that the function (pass_by_reference) doesn't manipulate a copy of the variable passed, but the actual variable itself.